# How i use the English translation as fallback in plugin ( Shopware 6 )

Tags: shopware

Hi i try to publish a plugin in the Shopware store.after review my plugin, from Shopware send to me an error.

```
The plugin cannot be installed. The plugin could not be installed due to the error message "Translation required for system language 2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b" The default language must be selected during installation.
```

I search about it and i found this [document](https://docs.shopware.com/en/account-en/manufacturer-area/quality-guidelines-for-extensions-in-the-community-store#fallback-language)

> Fallback language The installation is not always in English or German.
> So make sure that your extension works in other languages as well. An
> example: The customer has his installation in Spanish, your extension
> is not yet available in this language. So you should use the English
> translation as fallback.

I don't know how i can define default language in my plugin

**UPDATE**

Before than, I defined snippet file in service.yml without priority option

```
<service id="MyNamespace\Resources\snippet\en_GB\SnippetFile_en_GB" public="true">
   <tag name="shopware.snippet.file" />
</service>
<service id="MyNamespace\Resources\snippet\de_DE\SnippetFile_de_DE" public="true">
   <tag name="shopware.snippet.file"/>
</service>
```

Now it's

```
<service id="MyNamespace\Resources\snippet\en_GB\SnippetFile_en_GB" public="true">
   <tag name="shopware.snippet.file" priority="100"/>
</service>
<service id="MyNamespace\Resources\snippet\de_DE\SnippetFile_de_DE" public="true">
   <tag name="shopware.snippet.file" priority="100"/>
</service>
```

PS:I don't us of config.xml file.Is it possible that error relate to it.For example, User can select default the language in config plugin??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a better solution should be:

```
use Shopware\Core\Defaults;

...

'label' => [
     'en-GB' => 'my english label',
     'de-DE' => 'meine deutsche Beschriftung',
     Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => 'my default language label',
]

...
```

Best regards

Sebastian

Answer (score -1):

In my plugin i needed to insert data required in the **custom_field**
I useed install method.
and in there i only specified 2 language, but it is wrong.

```
'label' => [
           
             'en-GB' => 'custom field example',
             'de-DE' => 'Beispiel für ein benutzerdefiniertes Feld',
             '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b' => 'custom field example'
           ]
```

If customer has different default language like Spanish language,he/she get an error during the installation of the plugin.

I should have defined **Fallback language** as below

```
     /**
     * @param InstallContext $context
     */
public function install(InstallContext $context): void
    {
     parent::install($context);

 $customFieldSetRepository = $this->container->get('custom_field_set.repository');
   $customFieldSetRepository->create([
            [
                'name' => 'custom_field_example',
                'global' => true,
                'config' => [
                    'label' => [
                         'en-GB' => 'custom field example',
                         'de-DE' => 'Beispiel für ein benutzerdefiniertes Feld',
                         '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b' => 'custom field example
                    ]
                ],
                .
                .
                .
```